# How to apply Spark ALS for Implicit data

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I have dataset is history of purchase like this:

```
+---+-----------+---------+
|usn|    page_id|    click|
+---+-----------+---------+
| 11| 9000001012|       10|
|169| 2010008901|      100|
|169| 9000001007|        4|
|169| 2010788901|        1|
|169| 8750001007|        4|
|169| 9003601012|       10|
|169| 9000001007|        4|
|613| 9000050601|        8|
|613| 9000011875|        3|
|613| 2010010401|        6|
|613| 9000001007|        4|
|613| 2010008801|        1|
|836| 9000050601|       20|
|916| 9000050601|       10|
|916| 9000562601|       30|
|916| 9000001007|        4|
|916| 9000001012|       10|
+---+-----------+---------+
```

I have been read docs in Spark (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-collaborative-filtering.html) but i don't know how to use Collaborative Filtering for Implicit Preference in this problem.

And now i want to apply ALS for Implicit Preference to this dataset. 
How to do it? Can I apply this dataset for Explicit Data?

Please help me use it and Give me an example code python about Implicit Preference if you have

Comment: Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Do i assume **click** as ratings? and  Can i put this dataset to model ALS?
That is true?
And i need example for this: 

**als = ALS(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01, implicitPrefs=True,
          userCol="userId", itemCol="movieId", ratingCol="rating")**

with **implicitPrefs=True**

Comment: Yes they act as a rating. Just replace the args with the correct colnames of your dataset. If the results are way off, you can try normalizing the clicks.

Comment: so, Can you give me example code python about Implicit feedback

Comment: why do you need an example? you already have the code, just run it and see if it works.

Comment: because I don't know how is dataset Implicit and how to convert dataset Implicit to can use in ALS for Implicit Feedback

Comment: You don't convert anything, you just use these arguments: `implicitPrefs=True, userCol="usn", itemCol="page_id", ratingCol="click"`

Comment: I'm having some troubles understanding your question @PhongNguyen

Comment: My question mean I don't understand how is dataset for Implicit Preference and I need some example dataset to use in Implicit Preference

Answer (score 2):

A little late my answer, but the main thing is to scale the values de 'click'. In my case work:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

ww = Window.partitionBy("usn")
scaled_score = (
    0.00001 + 10*(col("click") - min("click").over(ww)) / (max("click").over(ww) - min("click").over(ww))
).cast(DecimalType(7, 5))
```

After creating a strategy for the most visiteds page_id, remember that the values to be modeled should reflect the client's tastes

Comment: why have you multiplied with 10 and added 0.00001, is the input still in the range of 0-1? also scaling needs to be done user wise?